# User Control showing in panel issue

Tags: c#, user-controls, panel

I have a mainForm that has 3 panels.  Panel3 is the one where I want my user control's to show.  On my main form if I have a button (on left menu) I use this code and it works great:

```
panel3.Controls.Clear();
UserControl2 userControl2 = new UserControl2();
userControl2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel3.Controls.Add(userControl2);
```

My issue is when I have a button on that User Control 2 and I want that button click to bring up a UC called Employee List.  It can't find panel 3.  So my question is how can I tie Employee list to open up in Main Form Panel 3 or is there a better way to do that?

UPDATE: I did this and it works.. but it creates another main form with my employee list UC open now in panel3.. how can I just have it open and not create another main form?

```
mainForm mf = new mainForm();
mf.panel3.Controls.Clear();
employeeList empList = new employeeList();
empList.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
mf.panel3.Controls.Add(empList);
mf.Show();
```

Comment: If I take the code above at put it on a button click event on the UserControl2 page... it can't find panel 3 which is on the mainForm.  So my question is how can I link them together?

Comment: You need to inject references, maybe in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code did it!

```
mainForm f1 = (mainForm)Application.OpenForms["mainForm"];          
f1.panel3.Controls.Clear();
employeeList empList = new employeeList();
empList.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
f1.panel3.Controls.Add(empList);
f1.Show();
```